# Postgres ALTER TABLE ...IDENTITY...SEQUENCE NAME syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a dump created by pg_dump 2.9 into postgres 13.4, however it fails on the ALTER TABLE ...IDENITY...SEQUENCE NAME

```
CREATE TABLE admin.bidtype (
    bidtype_id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    created_by integer,
    created_date timestamp without time zone,
    updated_by integer,
    updated_date timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_by integer,
    deleted_date timestamp without time zone
);


ALTER TABLE admin.bidtype OWNER TO app_bidhq;

--
-- Name: bidtype_bidtype_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: admin; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE admin.bidtype ALTER COLUMN bidtype_id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE name admin.bidtype_bidtype_id_seq
                       ^                      ^
                       |______________________|__________________ 
    START 1
          ^
          |______________________________________________________
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
    CYCLE
);
```

The error shown is "[42601] ERROR: syntax error at end of input Position: 132" and DataGrip highlights errors at the marked positions. I'm new to Postgres, but have checked the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altersequence.html. The syntax looks correct to me.

This is running on RDS for Postgres

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b2f8e4d696979e08608619a85ea30dd) are you sure you are using Postgres 13? What does `select version();` show you? There is also no "pg_dump 2.9" version.

Comment: Version is ```PostgreSQL 13.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit``` sorry, its pg_dump 12.9

Comment: Can you use pg_dump from Postgres 13? It's typically better to use the pg_dump version of the _target_ database.

Comment: Ok, I'll request that from the dumper and get back to you

Comment: But still: the syntax is correct and should work as you can see in my dbfiddle.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it actually works with psql, so the problem is limited to DataGrip it appears